# Create a table as, where 'date condition' in dynamic PL/SQL

Tags: plsql, dynamic-sql

I got assigned the following task.

Assume we have a table A structured with an id column and a date column.
Write a procedure in PL/SQL that: takes as parameters the table name (in our case A) and a date D, creates a backup table named A_bck containing only the records of A with dates < D and removes from the table A all the records inserted in A_bck.

[Here there is my code.](https://pastebin.com/g7ypdWpx)

Unluckily I get this error:

```
Error report -
ORA-00904: "MAY": invalid identifier
ORA-06512: at line 41
ORA-06512: at line 80
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
```

If I try to achieve the same result using a where condition on the id column instead that on the date one, I have no problems.
Where is the mistake? Am I implementing it completely in the wrong way?

Comment: It sounds like a date format model issue. What have you done so far?

Comment: Outside links may not be accessible for everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that as you're executing dynamic sql you're query is built up as a string. Oracle does not know that the date you've given is actually a date, it is simply being treated as part of the string. To solve this you should be able to do the following:

`my_query := 'CREATE TABLE ' || table_name_backup || ' AS (SELECT * FROM ' || table_name || ' WHERE table_date < to_date(''' || backup_date || '''))';`

This should sort out your issue for you. As a side note, you will probably want to change your "table_exists" query, as table names are all stored in upper case, e.g.

`SELECT COUNT(*) INTO table_exists FROM USER_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = upper(my_table);`

Edit: Further explanation following comment

To explain why you don't have the above problem when using integers, it is important to remember that using execute immediate simply executes the given string as an SQL query.

For example:

```
declare 
  x INTEGER := 1;
  i integer;
  my_query VARCHAR2(256);
begin
  my_query := 'select 1 from dual where 1 = ' || x;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE my_query INTO i;
end;
```

my_query in the above example would be executed as:

`select 1 from dual where 1 = 1`

which is perfectly valid sql. In your example however, you were ending up with something like this:

`CREATE TABLE abaco_bck AS (SELECT * FROM abaco WHERE table_date < 27-MAY-17)`

As it isn't wrapped in quotes, or explicitly converted to a date, the SQL engine is trying to subtract "MAY" from 27, but it doesn't know what "MAY" is.

One other thing to mention, is that for some operations you could use bind variables instead of quotes (although you can't for DDL) e.g.

```
declare 
  lToday    DATE := SYSDATE;
  i         INTEGER;
  my_query  VARCHAR2(256);
begin
  my_query := 'select 1 from dual where sysdate = :1';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE my_query INTO i USING lToday;
end;
```

Comment: Now everything makes sense! So, every time I need to create a dynamic SQL statement, the variables which are not strings must be escaped with ''. Mistakenly, I thought the concatenation was automatically doing the job. But then why if the variable is a number I don't get any error?

Comment: Added some more explanation which hopefully adds some clarification for you

Comment: Nice explanation. I'd slightly prefer `'where table_date < date ''' || backup_date || ''''` with `backup_date` formatted `YYYY-MM-DD`, though, to give `where table_date < date '2017-05-27'`.